# &nbsp; is displayed as colon (:) on google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

[image: capture]

[image: capture]

On both pictures Google Chrome displays `&nbsp;` as colon (`:`) .

I have tried to delete cookies, cached images, hosted app data etc no help.

The version is: Google Chrome   40.0.2214.111 (Official Build) m - the most recent one.

Also when i try to copy the colon and paste it somewhere else it does not appear.

I have opened the same things in Mozila and they work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with certain fonts in Chrome.  Different fonts display `&nbsp;` differently. It seems to be a problem introduced in v40:

[Issue 454108: `&nbsp;` in some fonts is displayed as symbol](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=454108)